# SL4A python при звонке вызывается skype, вместо обычного метота вызова абонента

Tags: python, android, python-2.x

При попытке сделать вызов из python при помощи такого кода

```
from androidhelper import Android
droid = Android()
droid.phoneCallNumber("+998901234567")
```

вызывается приложение скайпа, хотя по умолчанию должен работать обычный звонок абоненту.
Пробовал даже такой вариант вызова:

```
droid.phoneCall("tel:+998901234567")
```

Но при этом, если вызвать функцию набора номера

```
droid.phoneDialNumber("+998901234567")
```

То вызывается стандартное приложение дозвона.

Можно ли как нибудь заставить запускаться стандартное приложение при дозвоне?

Версия python 2.7.2 из пакета qpython. Версия SL4A - r6

Comment: Похоже, руками сменить в настройках dialer'a, каким приложением выполнять звонки.

Comment: dialer это приложение или конфиг в sl4a?

Comment: Dialer это приложение в самом андроиде.

Comment: Покопался в настройках dialer'a. Он установлен как приложение по умолчанию. Но по прежнему вместо него запускается скайп